# Replace multidimensional array value with new value

Tags: php, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

Currently I have this working code that will replace value from old multidimensional array with new value taken from db. Firstly I declare array for 12 month. Code below:

```
$base = Array(
    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-01',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-02',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-03',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ), 

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-04',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),               

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-05',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),               

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-06',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),               

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-07',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),


    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-08',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),               

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-09',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),               


    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-10',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-11',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),   

    Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-12',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
         )                                         
    );

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT brand, 
DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%Y' ) AS 'year', 
DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%m' ) AS 'month', 
SUM(brand='PZH') AS PZH,
SUM(brand='KFC') AS KFC,
SUM(brand='SUB') AS SUB
FROM scan_report WHERE DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%Y' ) =2010 AND id = ".$_SESSION['userinfo']['id']."
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( date_time, '%Y%m' )") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$num_rows = 1;  

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach($base as &$value) {

    echo $num_rows;     
    if ($value['month'] == $row['year'].'-'.$row['month']){     
        $value['KFC'] = $row['KFC'];
        $value['PZH'] = $row['PZH'];
        $value['SUB'] = $row['SUB'];

     }

}
$num_rows++;
}
```

because the multidimensional array, the `for each` loop for 12 times. During echo there were 60 loop for 5 matched record when query from db. Is there any elegant solution than what I'm currently doing? Any idea to reduce loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot would be to take the `month` value and use it as the key in your array:

```
$base = Array(
    '2010-01' => Array
        (
            "month" => '2010-01',
            "KFC" => '0',
            "PZH" => '0',
            "SUB" => '0'
        ),
     // ... and so on
    );
```

Then you can search as such:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $searchKey = $row['year'].'-'.$row['month'];
    if (isset($base[$searchKey])) {
        $base[$searchKey]['KFC'] = $row['KFC'];
        $base[$searchKey]['PZH'] = $row['PZH'];
        $base[$searchKey]['SUB'] = $row['SUB'];
    } else {
        $base[$searchKey] = array(
            'KFC' => $row['KFC'],
            'PZH' => $row['PZH'],
            'SUB' => $row['SUB'],
        );
    }
    $num_rows++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not predefine the array values and would prefer to use year-month as key (it's unique because it's grouped by that).

```
$base = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $num_rows;
    $key = $row['year'].'-'.$row['month'];
    $base[$key] = array();
    $base[$key]['KFC'] = $row['KFC'];
    $base[$key]['PZH'] = $row['PZH'];
    $base[$key]['SUB'] = $row['SUB'];
    $num_rows++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use associate multidimensional arrays in cases like this. For example, you could arrange your base array as follows:

```
$base = array('2010-01' => array(
        "KFC" => '0',
        "PZH" => '0',
        "SUB" => '0'
    ),
    '2010-01' => array(
        "month" => '',
        "KFC" => '0',
        "PZH" => '0',
        "SUB" => '0'
    ) //etc
    );
```

Then, when your processing your results from the database you can access a specific section of the $base  array like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$base[$row['year'] . '-' . $row['month']]['KFC'] = $row['KFC'];
$base[$row['year'] . '-' . $row['month']]['PZH'] = $row['pZH'];
$base[$row['year'] . '-' . $row['month']]['SUB'] = $row['SUB'];

}
```

Then you only have to loop through the database rows to achieve the updating process. Make sense?

Comment: Sorry, other people beat me to it apparently.